# What is the name and meaning of .. (two dots) operator in yq?

Tags: operators, punctuation, yq

#### Examples

I see in the `yq` examples the following expression:

```
yq eval '.. | select(...)' ...
```

or:

```
yq eval '.. | .something' ...
```

#### Research

(Google search not helpful here either). Also if you don't know the name of this operator, it is hard to find it in the `yq` documentation, unless I brute-force it.)

#### Question

What does `..` mean in yq?

Comment: Maybe the [recursive descent](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob) operator. Though I don't think it's used that way so it's probably a placeholder.

Comment: Which yq version are you using the Go or the Python version? see the yq tag info for the difference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate the [comment by Ouroborus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72837561/what-is-the-yq-operator/72837680?noredirect=1#comment128651800_72837561):

#### Recursive Descent `..` (two dots)

In the Go implementation of yq the documentation names this *operator* [**Recursive Descent (Glob)**, match values form](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob#match-values-form-):

> This operator recursively matches (or globs) all children nodes given of a particular element, including that node itself. This is most often used to apply a filter recursively against all matches. It can be used in either the
>
> **match values form `..`**
> This will, like the `jq` equivalent, recursively match all value nodes. Use it to find/manipulate particular values.

#### Compare similar operator used by jq

Since `yq` is the YAML equivalent for `jq` (predecessor for JSON), you can deduct name and semantics from a look at jq's documentation for [Recursive Descent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..):

> **Recursive Descent: `..`**
>
> Recursively descends `.`, producing every value. This is the same as the zero-argument `recurse` builtin (see below). This is intended to resemble the XPath `//` operator. Note that ..a does not work; use `..|.a` instead. In the example below we use `..|.a?` to find all the values of object keys "a" in any object found "below" `.`.